# Text wrapping in cell spanning over multiple rows - Sphinx ReStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext

When creating a table with cell spanning over multiple rows I notice that the contents of the text don't wrap but increase the width of the table to produce horizontal scroll bars.

For example consider the following RST,

```
+-------+-----------------+
|       |                 |
+-------+-----------------+
|       | This text must  |
+-------+ wrap over to    |
|       | the next line   |
+-------+-----------------+
```

when built produces,

[image: sphynx-build output]

As I increase the length of the text, the table grows horizontally. what should I do for it to wrap? For now, I'm forcing it to wrap by manually inserting line breaks with "|" but the produced output looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`table` directive with a `:widths:` attribute](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table).

```
.. table::
    :widths: 20, 80

    +-------+-----------------+
    |       |                 |
    +-------+-----------------+
    |       | This text must  |
    +-------+ wrap over to    |
    |       | the next line   |
    +-------+-----------------+
```

There might also be a way to control column widths with custom CSS, but I was not able to override the `<colgroup>` tags in the Sphinx output.

Comment: Controlling width with CSS and table width attributes are workarounds. The table width keeps increasing (setting up horizontal scroll) with the text in one line. Is this an expected behavior? if so isn't it more logical to expect it to wrap around?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to override the `colgroup` tag in Sphinx. You could try using the [rst2html5 package](https://pypi.org/project/rst2html5/) instead, which doesn't generate `colgroup`. Another option is using CSS to control column widths:

```css
col:nth-child(1) {
  width: 200px;
}

col:nth-child(2) {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="docutils">
<colgroup>
<col width="29%" />
<col width="71%" />
</colgroup>
<tbody valign="top">
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td rowspan="2">This text must
wrap over to
the next line</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot switch to anything else. Need to figure this out here.